# How to frugal `git clone` for `git log` only?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-log

I just want to clone a repository to extract the author and email info each commit. Is there a way to only `git clone` what is needed for `git log`?

Comment: See my answer below.  I didn't include this in the answer (bc it doesn't answer your question), but: Generally this just isn't necessary. It *sounds like* a nice way to be efficient, but it's pretty rare for a `clone` to actually be that expensive, and if it is then that might point to another problem that should be solved.  (For example, repos that should use `lfs` but don't use it tend to take a long enough time to clone to make this an issue.)

Comment: Some repo has large files or sometimes the network is extremely slow. In those case, it would be helpful to just close the metadata used by git log.

Comment: As I already said, if there are such large files to be a problem, then probably the repo should be using LFS.  Regardless it makes no difference to argue with me about whether it's a necessary feature; it is not a feature of git.

Answer (score 1):

There is not.  `git` is designed to work locally.  Some hosting software might provide solutions, but git itself expects you to copy the commits *and the content on which they depend* before you can do things like `log`